# Could not rename directory to save settings file in Virtualbox when running vagrant up

Tags: scrapy, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to learn scraping by following the 'Learning Scrapy' book.
According to the book, the following should create a working VM:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook.git

$ cd scrapybook

You can then start the Vagrant system by typing:

$ vagrant up --no-parallel

This will take some time the first time you run it - depending on your internet connection.
After the first time, `vagrant up` should be instantaneous. As soon as your system is up,
you can log in to your virtual dev machine with:

$ vagrant ssh

However, I keep getting the following error:
VirtualBox error:

VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not rename the directory 'C:\Users\20150624\VirtualBox VMs\docker-provider_1548254069678_53356' to 'C:\Users\20150624\VirtualBox VMs\docker-provider' to save the settings file (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "SaveSettings()" at line 3194 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

Does anyone know how to get this up and running?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try ssh into another vm ? `vagrant ssh web` for example

Comment: Try https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/2813#issuecomment-32187118